# Build fails because repo pull fails with repository exists or timeout waiting for lock

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

### Summary

I've got a build in TeamCity using Mercurial as the VCS and it's repeatedly failing for one of these two reasons:

1. `hg init` - repository already exists, except I deleted the whole directory before this so it definitely didn't exist.
2. `hg pull` - timed out waiting for lock, but the lock it's waiting for seems to be its own lock.

I'm really hoping that someone has come across this before, or might be able to give me some ideas for how to troubleshoot it anyway.

### Setup

- I'm using TortoiseHg as the mercurial client, and I've updated it
  (and hence Mercurial) to version 4.6.1 on both the build server and
  agent.
- The agent is running on a Windows 7 VM.
  I have a Windows 10 VM with the same TeamCity/Mercurial setup that's
  working fine.
- The repo being pulled from is located on a network share.
- The folder being pulled to is on a secondary drive on the VM.

The two problems I'm seeing are as follows:

### 1. Hg init failure

Steps:

1. Manually delete the whole working directory from the buildagent, so that's .hg folder and it's parent folder.
   The working folder doesn't even exist now, so TeamCity will have to completely recreate the folder.
2. Run build on TeamCity, with clean all files selected.
3. Build starts, creates directory and calls `hg init`.
4. Error message that hg init failed because the "repository already exists".
5. When I look at the directory I can see a .hg folder, and some files inside it including a wlock file.

### 2. Pull failure

Steps:

1. Leave the working directory from problem 1 in place, including the .hg directory.
2. Ensure any lock files are deleted and hg recover has been run just in case.
3. Run build on TeamCity, without cleaning the directory.
4. The logs show hg pull starting and bundling files, but also says "waiting for lock on working directory of E:\blah held by process '3408' on host 'BUILDAGENT'
   3408 here is an example, the number changes every time and corresponds to the hg.exe process that seems to be doing the pull.
5. Eventually after a lot of bundling and files messages I'll get a message saying it timed out waiting for the lock.
   But of course the lock it's waiting for seems to be the lock it's holding itself!
6. If I delete the wlock file during this time, I'll see messages saying "got lock after X seconds" and immediately after it "waiting for lock on repository E:\blah held by process '3408' on host 'BUILDAGENT'. Then eventually it'll fail with a message about an abandoned transaction.

---

Does anyone have any ideas?